# Failed to execute goal org.eclipse.tycho:tycho-packaging-plugin:0.22.0:build-qualifier (default-build-qualifier) on project org.talend.libraries

Tags: java, git, maven, talend

I am trying to build talend source code. After hours (24hrs) of build process, it gets failed and the error is,

Failed to execute goal org.eclipse.tycho:tycho-packaging-plugin:0.22.0:build-qualifier (default-build-qualifier) on project org.talend.libraries.apache.common: No git repository found searching upwards from C:\Users\Kiran Ramanadham\Downloads\t1\tcommon-studio-se-master\main\plugins\org.talend.libraries.apache.common -> [Help 1]

Can any one please help me in solving this error.
Thank you.

Comment: Do you have Git installed in your computer?

Comment: Actually no. But i found another post where similar error was posted. My build happened successfully now after installing git and cloning the code using the 'git clone' cmd. Thank you.